# How to pass text and images through multiple pages and preview in the final page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 4 CreatePoll pages for my polling app.

1. CreatePoll1 is to add the questions and the options
2. CreatePoll2 is to add the caption, duration and category
3. CreatePoll3 is to add the images
4. CreatePoll4 is to preview all the details in the form of a card view, as it will look once it is posted.

Images: [CreatePoll1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xwj9.jpg) [CretePoll2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC9DL.jpg) [CreatePoll3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYHl2.jpg) [CreatePoll4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAyBc.jpg)

How do I pass the data from all these CreatePoll pages and finally display it in the last preview page?

CreatePoll1 PageRoute:

> ```
>  MaterialButton(
>        onPressed: () {
>          Navigator.push(
>           context,
>             MaterialPageRoute(
>                 builder: (context) => CreatePoll2(),
>                 ),
>               );
>              },
>               color: Colors.black,
>               textColor: Colors.white,
>               child: Icon(
>               Icons.arrow_forward,
>               size: 24,
>               ),
>               padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
>               shape: CircleBorder(),
>               ),
> ```

CreatePoll2 Page Route:

> ```
>  MaterialButton(
>        onPressed: () {
>          Navigator.push(
>           context,
>             MaterialPageRoute(
>                 builder: (context) => CreatePoll3(),
>                 ),
>               );
>              },
>               color: Colors.black,
>               textColor: Colors.white,
>               child: Icon(
>               Icons.arrow_forward,
>               size: 24,
>               ),
>               padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
>               shape: CircleBorder(),
>               ),
> ```

CreatePoll3 Page Route:

> ```
>  MaterialButton(
>        onPressed: () {
>          Navigator.push(
>           context,
>             MaterialPageRoute(
>                 builder: (context) => CreatePoll4(),
>                 ),
>               );
>              },
>               color: Colors.black,
>               textColor: Colors.white,
>               child: Icon(
>               Icons.arrow_forward,
>               size: 24,
>               ),
>               padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
>               shape: CircleBorder(),
>               ),
> ```

CreatePoll4 Page Route:

> ```
>  MaterialButton(
>        onPressed: () {
>          Navigator.push(
>           context,
>             MaterialPageRoute(
>                 builder: (context) => Nav(),
>                 ),
>               );
>              },
>               color: Colors.black,
>               textColor: Colors.white,
>               child: Icon(
>               Icons.arrow_forward,
>               size: 24,
>               ),
>               padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
>               shape: CircleBorder(),
>               ),
> ```

Complete Code for CreatePoll Pages:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Nz7Zk1PFzE3y4Zo_QbJoGTImrm_Q9AYHVvgy3KEtfYo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't pass them. Use a state management solution to keep track of all the details (access and save new status in memory), and then access them in your final page - or wherever you need them (eg Provider, bloc, Riverpod, redux etc etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update after looking at code:

I'll give you an example of doing this with a string value using [GetX State Management](https://pub.dev/packages/get). This can be done with any state management solution but I find this to be the fastest and easiest to use and I suggest checking it out if you're not familiar with it. Either way, its in your benefit to learn at least one of the solutions so that this type of stuff will be easier for you going forward. Provider or its updated version Riverpod would be another good one to start with.

Using this solution all your pages can become stateless because the text editing controllers are being initialized in in the PollDataController class.

For every unique textfield you have, create a dedicated text editing controller for it in the PollDataController (GetX Controller class) class below. Every value you need to display needs to be a variable in the PollDataController class. The example below is an RxString that listens to the text editing controller and its value is updated whenever the textfield is changed.

```
class PollDataController extends GetxController {
  TextEditingController nameController;
  RxString name = ''.obs; // adding .obs makes this a stream based observable String

// this onInit override can be used instead of initState in a stateful widget. 
// All text editing controllers can be initialized here
  @override 
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    nameController = TextEditingController();
    nameController.addListener(() {
      name.value = nameController.text; // the RxString is automatically updated with whatever is input in the textfield
    });
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    nameController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Initialize your GetX controller, this can be done on a page or on the start of your app, but it needs to be done before trying to use the controller so for simplicity, put this in your main method before running the app.

```
Get.put(PollDataController());
```

Then access variables in the GetX class from anywhere in the app by "finding" the initialized controller.

```
final pollDataController = Get.find<PollDataController>();
```

To access the already initialized text editing controller from that class:

```
final _nameController = pollDataController.nameController;
```

Then when you want to display the updated value in your UI, there are a few different ways to do this with GetX. Wrapping your text widget in an Obx widget is one of the ways. This widget will automatically be rebuilt anytime the value of the variable changes.

```
Obx(()=> Text(pollDataController.name.value)); // use .value at the end of the variable to access the actual value of the RxString
```

So whats happening here is anywhere you use that text editing controller in the textfield, the RxString name is updated with that value and you can access it from anywhere in the app using the method above.

So this will still require some work on your end but I gave you an example of doing this with a string, but all basic data types are supported ie RxInt, RxList etc...

Any piece of data you want to display on the last page can be accessed via the pollDataController.

When it comes to images, looks like you're using an external package, but generally I manage dynamic images with AssetImage() and the assetName (path) is just another RxString.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Original Answer:

You’ll need to post more code than just your buttons if you want someone to write up a potential solution for you.

But to add to what @Agreensh said: The idea is you pick a state management solution, and each CreatePoll page populates the data on the separate state management class outside of the UI, without passing arguments from page to page.

Then by the time you get to your last page, the data is already populated and you just need to display it from the state management class. If you post the full code from your pages to show what’s going on with your text fields and drop down lists etc...I can try and help you out.

Comment: Due to the character restriction in StackOverflow, I'm unable to share the complete code. But I have attached a link to Google Docs with the complete code.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my code and help me out

Comment: Can GetxController be used alongside Stateful Class?

My Textfield is in the Stateful Class and the text controller which is to control the text is in another class i.e pollDataController class.

So, how do I go about it?

Comment: Yes it can. But unless there's another reason to have a stateful widget then you might as well use stateless. But I suggest getting what you need working and then, if you're so inclined, convert your pages to Stateless afterwards. Trying to switch to stateless before it's all working the way you want at this point won't  do you any favors.

Comment: I showed you how to use the text controller in from pollDataController class in my answer.   

Add this to your build method:

 `final pollDataController = Get.find<PollDataController>();` then `final _nameController = pollDataController.nameController;
 ` Then use _nameController as your text editing controller for the textfield in your stateful class. 

You would not be using any local text editing controllers with this setup so you can get rid of the one you already had.

Comment: Did you hot restart? If its in the main method it gets initialized only on app restart. Not hot reload.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for text now, I have to try the same for images. Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: This works fine for the Question text field and the option1 text field, but from option2 text field it is getting dynamically generated, how do I specify a unique textcontroller for the dynamically generated text fields.

Comment: Add as many text editing controllers as you need in the GetX controller class and access them the same way you already did.

Comment: Can you please help me out with the dropdown menu as well?

Comment: When I use the setState() value of the Dropdown Menu and pass it through a RxString, the value comes as null